# How set date filter with start and end date django rest framwork

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have view.py

```
class eventList(ListAPIView):
queryset = Event.objects.all().filter(is_active=1, is_approved=1)
serializer_class = eventSerializer
filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend,
                   filters.SearchFilter, filters.OrderingFilter]
search_fields = ['event_name', 'event_address', 'start_date', 'start_time', 'end_time', 'age_max',
                 'age_min', 'event_organizer__name', 'event_type__name', 'event_city__name', 'event_tag__name']

filterset_fields = ['id', 'event_name', 'start_date', 'start_time', 'end_date', 'end_time',
                    'age_max', 'age_min', 'event_organizer', 'event_type', 'event_city', 'event_tag']

ordering_fields = '__all__'
ordering = ['-start_date']
```

how I get events on the basis **start_date** date range like

http://192.168.0.115:8000/api/allEvents/?start_date__gte=2019-11-16&start_date__lt=2019-11-24

I want this on **filterset_fields**, How achieved this scenario

Comment: You need to write [**`filterset_class`**](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/rest_framework.html#adding-a-filterset-with-filterset-class)

Answer (score 1):

Got this solution

- double underscore **gte** is for greater than equal to
- double underscore **gt** is for greater than
- double underscore **lte** is for less than equal to
- double underscore **lt** is for less than

  ```
  filterset_fields = {
      'start_date':['gte', 'lte', 'exact', 'gt', 'lt'],
      'id':['exact'],
      'event_name':['exact'],
      'start_time':['exact'],
      'end_date':['exact'],
      'end_time':['exact'],
      'age_max':['gte', 'lte', 'exact', 'gt', 'lt'],
      'age_min':['gte', 'lte', 'exact', 'gt', 'lt'],
      'event_organizer__name':['exact'],
      'event_type__name':['exact'],
      'event_city__name':['exact'],'event_tag__name':['exact']
  }
  ```